# How to streamline file moving script?

Tags: python, performance, shutil

I wrote a clunky script to move specific files located in one folder to three different folders.  The three lists specify which files should be grouped and moved to a new folder.  Although this script works, it is really ugly and inefficient.  How can I improve on the structure of this script to help make the file-moving process more elegant and streamlined?

```
import os, shutil

# Location of input files
os.chdir = r'C:\path\to\input_imagery'
ws = os.chdir

# Lists of file sets that need to moved
area1 = ["4111201_ne.tif", "4111201_nw.tif"]
area2 = ["4111202_ne.tif", "4111202_nw.tif"]
area3 = ["4111207_nw.tif", "4111301_ne.tif"]

# Output folders
folder_area1 = r'C:\out\area1'
folder_area2 = r'C:\out\area2'
folder_area3 = r'C:\out\area3'

for area in area1:
    input1 = os.path.join(ws, area)
    output1 = os.path.join(folder_area1, area)
    shutil.move(input1, output1)

for area in area2:
    input1 = os.path.join(ws, area)
    output1 = os.path.join(folder_area2, area)
    shutil.move(input1, output1)

for area in area3:
    input1 = os.path.join(ws, area)
    output1 = os.path.join(folder_area3, area)
    shutil.move(input1, output1)
```

Comment: Are you sure you can't just use a regular shell script and `mv`/`find` instead of Python?

Comment: Or PowerShell in this case?

Comment: Eventually, I will need scale this up and incorporate some advanced file locating tools in the `arcpy` site-package which I omitted in the script for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pack it all up

```
to_move = [
  [ 'source_dir1', 'target_dir1', { 'source_file' : 'dest_file', 'source2' : 'dest2'}]
  [ 'source_dir2', 'target_dir2', { 'source_file' : 'dest_file', 'source2' : 'dest2'}]
  ]
```

and then iterate over it all.

I use a dictionary for the files because you are moving them. This guarantees that your sources are unique in a dict.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it:

```
import os, shutil

# Location of input files
os.chdir = r'C:\path\to\input_imagery'
ws = os.chdir

filestomove = [
    {
        'dest': r'C:\out\area1',
        'files': ["4111201_ne.tif", "4111201_nw.tif"]
    },
    {
        'dest': r'C:\out\area2',
        'files': ["4111201_ne.tif", "4111202_nw.tif"]
    }
]

for o in filestomove:   
    [shutil.move(os.path.join(ws, f),
                 os.path.join(o['dest'], f)) for f in o['files']]
```

I think it explicit and clear.